# Correct way to use dotenv-expand (.env)

Tags: node.js, dotenv

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand

```
POSTGRES_DB=postgresdb
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_USER=postgresadmin
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
PORT=3000
DATABASE_URL=postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}
```

Is it correct way to use `dotenv-expand`? If so , it doens't work in my case . I want to create variable related to variables above:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}
```

but when I check it by using `process.env.DATABASE_URL` - it returns me the same varialbe like you see above without changing `${POSTGRES_USER}` on the corresponding parameter

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import dotenvExpand from 'dotenv-expand';

const config = dotenv.config();

dotenvExpand(config);
```

And here you can see how I initialize `dotenv-expand` with `dotenv`

Comment: Your file looks fine. How do you read the .env file in your code?

Comment: process.env.DATABASE_URL and I get  - postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB} as I wrote

Comment: does `console.log(dotenvExpand(config).parsed)` show it?

Comment: dotenvExpand(config).parsed.DATABASE_URL - this shows what I need, is it correct approach?

Comment: was just going from [tests](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand/blob/master/test/main.js)

Answer (score 3):

Using your code, like:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import dotenvExpand from 'dotenv-expand';

const config = dotenv.config();

dotenvExpand(config);

console.log(config);
```

I get the following error:

```
(node:23421) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
```

Changing your code to:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand');

const config = dotenv.config();

dotenvExpand(config);

console.log(config);
```

I get the desired output:

```
{
  parsed: {
    POSTGRES_DB: 'postgresdb',
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password',
    POSTGRES_USER: 'postgresadmin',
    POSTGRES_HOST: 'localhost',
    POSTGRES_PORT: '5432',
    PORT: '3000',
    DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgresadmin:password@localhost:5432/postgresdb'
  }
}
```

If you want to stick to `import`, add `"type": "module"` to your package.json.

**Edit:**

`console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);` works fine.

**My whole setup:**

```
mkdir dotenv-test && cd dotenv-test
npm init -y
npm install dotenv dotenv-expand
touch .env
rouch .index.js
(copying .env and code)
node index.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thought that I have to get it in process.env )

Comment: yes, it is fine ) Thanks ) And one more question . Sould I initialize :
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand');
const config = dotenv.config();
dotenvExpand(config);

for each page where I want to get this variable, because without it - it doesn't work . In different file I mean , not in app.js

Comment: Normally you would set your environment variables only once at top level. Then you can access them via `process.env` within the current Node.js process. From [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv): _As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv._ Same for dotenv-expand.

Answer (score 3):

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import dotenvExpand from 'dotenv-expand';

const config = dotenv.config();
```

Try to replace

```
dotenvExpand(config);
```

with

```
dotenvExpand.expand(config);
```